# Choose bands for LST (Landsat 8) in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, landsat-8

I want to get LST from Landsat 8. I prefer to use Google Earth Engine(GEE), and use the code that they are offer:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=Examples%3ADatasets%2FLANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2

I'm not sure what bands to use in that code to get LST.

Comment: You can check the Landsat 8 band designations [here](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-are-band-designations-landsat-satellites?qt-news_science_products=0#qt-news_science_products). It would be good to specify what you mean by LST. I'm guessing Land Surface Temperature?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.